# Get current view

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an app which has split view inside a tab bar, and these split views often have navigation hierarchy and then sometimes modal views are presents on top of them, and it all works fine, but...

I am trying to display a passcode lock whenever the app goes into background, so I put

```
[self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:lockView animated:YES];
```

in my AppDelegate's method

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

...which works fine unless a modal view is displayed. 
the passcode does not display if a modal view is open.

Is there a way to retrieve the currently active view controller so I can present this lock view?

Thanks in advance

Cheerio

---

Code that worked was as follows:

```
BOOL hasKids = YES;
UIViewController *topViewController = (UIViewController*)[[(UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:((UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController).selectedIndex];

while (hasKids) {
    if (topViewController.presentedViewController) {
        hasKids = YES;
        topViewController = topViewController.presentedViewController;
    } else {
        hasKids = NO;
    }
}

[topViewController presentModalViewController:lockView animated:YES];`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to keep track of which tab is currently active (there are a number of ways to do this, but I'd recommend implementing the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` and handling its `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` method).

Once that's done, you'll probably need to manage a property in each view controller that holds any modal view controllers you present. If, however, you're on iOS 5 or higher, look into the `UIViewController` property `presentedViewController`. It appears that this is a new way to do exactly what you want.

Comment: I think I can access the selected tab property of the tab bar through the app delegate without tabbar delegate, but my question now is whether having, let's say, the following hierarchy, whether 'presented view controller' would work...

tabbar-->split view-->nav-->pushed view-->pushed view-->modal view-->modal view

Comment: Tim, I'm pretty sure this is exactly why they implemented the new `presentedViewController` property in iOS 5. Take a look at the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW1). I think it's what you want, isn't it?

Comment: It sounds like I'll have to loop through the viewcontroller stack until there are no more presentedViewControllers, but this may possibly do the trick. Thanks.